# Initial Data Load With ActionBar Indeterminate ProgressBar

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-actionbar

I have a Indeterminate Progress Bar replacing my MenuItem refresh button while an AsyncTask loads data. All of this works without issue:

My create options menu:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {


    inflater.inflate(R.menu.videos, menu);
    menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.button_refresh);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

}
```

Asynchronous Task:

```
class ReviewLoaderAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<Review>> implements Api {

    private Context context;
    private int offset;
    private FragmentCallback mFragmentCallback;
    ArrayList<Review> add;



    public ReviewLoaderAsyncTask(Context _context, int _offset, FragmentCallback _mFragmentCallback)
    {

        context = _context;
        offset = _offset;
        mFragmentCallback = _mFragmentCallback;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        menuItem.setActionView(R.layout.progressbar); //ERROR OCCURS HERE
        menuItem.expandActionView();
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Review> doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        // Call some data here

        return add;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Review> _reviews) {
        super.onPostExecute(_reviews);
        menuItem.collapseActionView();
        menuItem.setActionView(null);
        mFragmentCallback.taskIsFinished(_reviews, offset);
    }


}
```

This all works fine. However, I want to begin loading this data as soon as the view is created. I do this inside my onCreateView portion

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view  = inflater.inflate(R.layout.review_fragment_gridview, container, false);
    mGridView = (StaggeredGridView) view.findViewById(R.id.myGrid);

    reviews = new ArrayList<Review>();
    offset = 0;
    ReviewLoaderAsyncTask loadRSSTask = new ReviewLoaderAsyncTask(getActivity(), offset, new FragmentCallback() {
        @Override
        public void taskIsFinished(ArrayList<Review> add, int _offset) {
            for (Review v : add) {
                reviews.add(v);
            }
            mReviewsAdapter = new ReviewsAdapter(getActivity(), reviews, getFragmentManager());
            offset = _offset;
            mGridView.setAdapter(mReviewsAdapter);
        }
    });
    if(savedInstanceState == null){
        loadRSSTask.execute();
    } else{
        reviews = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList(REVIEWS_LIST_TAG);
        ReviewsAdapter adapter = new ReviewsAdapter(getActivity(), reviews, getFragmentManager());
        mGridView.setAdapter(adapter);
        ((BaseAdapter) mGridView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    return view;
}
```

The problem I run in to is that the AsyncTask starts prior to the inflation of the menu. This results in a NullPointerException when I get to the PreExecute portion of my AsyncTask.

Is there a better implementation to begin the data load in the onCreateView and still keep my ProgressBar actionview?

Comment: Did you try and move the load to a later stage of the lifecycle, for example onResume?

Comment: Just tried. I received the same error at the PreExecute stage.

Comment: @cYrixmorten Based on your feedback, I added the    if(savedInstanceState == null){loadRSSTask.execute();} to the onCreateOptions menu. This is working, but I feel like it's bad form. If anyone else has a better suggestion, please let me know.

Comment: Think it is actually ok to place it inside onCreateOptions as you rely on the menuItem. This also allows you to pass the menuItem as a parameter to the constructor of ReviewLoaderAsyncTask, which would also make sense to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on feedback from cYrixmorten, I moved the Async execute call to the onCreateOptionsMenu. Here is the modified code.

Modified onCreateView:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view  = inflater.inflate(R.layout.review_fragment_gridview, container, false);
    mGridView = (StaggeredGridView) view.findViewById(R.id.myGrid);
    bundle = savedInstanceState;
    reviews = new ArrayList<Review>();
    offset = 0;
    ReviewLoaderAsyncTask loadRSSTask = new ReviewLoaderAsyncTask(getActivity(), offset, new FragmentCallback() {
        @Override
        public void taskIsFinished(ArrayList<Review> add, int _offset) {
            for (Review v : add) {
                reviews.add(v);
            }
            System.out.println(reviews.size() +" is the video size!");
            mReviewsAdapter = new ReviewsAdapter(getActivity(), reviews, getFragmentManager());
            offset = _offset;
            mGridView.setAdapter(mReviewsAdapter);
        }
    });
    if(savedInstanceState!=null){
        reviews = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList(REVIEWS_LIST_TAG);
        ReviewsAdapter adapter = new ReviewsAdapter(getActivity(), reviews, getFragmentManager());
        mGridView.setAdapter(adapter);
        ((BaseAdapter) mGridView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    return view;
}
```

Modified onCreateOptionsMenu:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {


    inflater.inflate(R.menu.videos, menu);
    menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.button_refresh);


    ReviewLoaderAsyncTask loadRSSTask = new ReviewLoaderAsyncTask(getActivity(), offset, new FragmentCallback() {
        @Override
        public void taskIsFinished(ArrayList<Review> add, int _offset) {
            System.out.println(add.size() + "is the passed array size to the callback");
            for (Review v : add) {
                reviews.add(v);
            }
            mReviewsAdapter = new ReviewsAdapter(getActivity(), reviews, getFragmentManager());
            offset = _offset;
            mGridView.setAdapter(mReviewsAdapter);
        }
    });
    if(bundle == null){
        loadRSSTask.execute();
    }



    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

}
```

This works, but I will not mark it as the solution for now in hopes to promote more discussion and alternative solutions to this question.